# iOS Core data migration to another machine

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, data-migration

I received the source for an application from a guy to make a few changes in the app. The data model version was, say, App3. I had to add about 3-4 more data model versions in the process. So the active model version when I sent him was App7

I built the project (it was running properly on my mac)
I sent him the zip and when he ran, he got the error "Can't find model for source store"
I had him create the latest data model again, based on the data model App3 and make it the same as App7 and set it as the current version.

He still has the error and I can't figure out why? Are the intermediate data model version causing issues? Is it required to delete the sqlite file in the application support->iphone simulator folder? I am all over the place with this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both model files and have some sort of versioning in place. The new model that you made will no longer work with his data file unless you specify to Core Data that you want it to update the data.

Versioning isn't that easy, but if your changes are small enough, you might be able to get away with automatic versioning. Read the guide and see:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: Retaining data here isn't necessary. The app should simply build and run. Updating the model is causing the problem. If he deletes the data file on his mac, will it solve?

Comment: @AyushChaudhary well, assuming that his data isn't important to him.

Comment: Not really important. Plus, the data model change is more like a complete overhaul. Many, many attributes added. It'll be syncing with a web server. So keeping these two points in mind, I think deleting the sqlite(a sort of fresh install) is the best option. What say?

Comment: If his data isn't important, and nobody else using the app has important data, just delete the sqlite file (or ask him to) and create a new one. Versioning is only useful in production, or to avoid re-creating data sets when you're testing. Sounds like the changes here are too big to even bother.

Comment: During deployment when I push the update, I should delete the file programmatically for the users, right?

Comment: It depends on whether their data is important or not. If it's something like cache data, you can delete it. If it's something like their list of favorite movies (which they created) you'll have to version it or your users won't be happy.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, it will. But really that is not the thing to do if ultimately the versioning is going to happen on existing live apps too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. You meant deleting the sqlite file?

Comment: Yes, deleting the SQLite data store should solve the error. But all the existing data is going to be lost, so take back up before deleting.

Comment: It did solve. Although retaining data isn't necessary in this case, but I have 2 questions :

Comment: 1. Why did I not have to do it while development on my machine?
2. When I release it to users, can I programmatically delete the sqlite db file?
3. What if I want to retain the data?

Comment: 1. Are you certain you did not have this error in your machine? Check in the Finder that you already have a store. Make any change to the data model in XCode (add a new attribute/change the type of an existing one, etc.), save the project and run it. The same error should come for you too.   2. I would think 'yes', but you should not do it.    3. Check the link Nevan has given above. Core Data Model versioning is a thing in itself.

Answer (score 0):

For the light-weight migration to work, you need to send him all the intermediate versions of the model as well since the migration takes place stage by stage through all versions.

And you have to make sure that you have made no modification (even accidentally) to the base version App3.